# Broadleaf spring session

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session, broadleaf-commerce

Trying to figure out how to integrate spring session with an app based on the broadleaf framework and so far it was unsuccessful, tried importing the BroadleafJdbcHttpSessionConfiguration config but it was to no success. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BroadleafJdbcHttpSessionConfiguration class was added primarily to better support multi-session customer assisted shopping for Customer Service Representatives.  The instructions for setting up the BroadleafJdbcHttpSessionConfiguration is in this context.  See https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/enterprise/current/multi-customer-assisted-shopping

If you are trying to introduce distributed session management, BroadleafJdbcHttpSessionConfiguration is an option but not recommended.  We recommend using Memcached with the Tomcat Session Manager.  See https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager/wiki/SetupAndConfiguration

The configuration for Memcached and Tomcat Session Manager is pretty easy and it works well.